Google Sheet Concatenate + Filter
I have a data table in Google Sheet and I wanted to create a formula to display a concatenated list of specific items from the table in 1 cell only. My spreadsheet sample shows the formula I am using in cell F1.
I have been struggling to figure out a way to turn this formula into a simple list of all available items in this fashion:
U-001 Tiger Claw Plastic Toy x 10
U-005 Zombie Barbie x 35

I wanted 1 cell to display the result SKU + " " + Description + " x " + Qty. I tried using Concatenate as shown in F10 but obviously this does not work. Is there a way to modify a filtered data to display differently as above?

You can use BYROW in your filtered list, and concatenate the values as desired. INDEX is used to access the three columns of each row (you can also use CHOOSECOLUMNS):
=BYROW(FILTER($B:$D,SEARCH("Available",$A:$A)),LAMBDA(each,
INDEX(each,,1)&" "&INDEX(each,,2)&" x "&INDEX(each,,3)))


Other option with ARRAYFORMULA, simpler in its expression but it concatenates before filtering (it may be heavier if the table has too many rows):
=FILTER($B:$B&" "&$C:$C&" x "&$D:$D,SEARCH("Available",$A:$A))



Thanks Martin, this works. I never heard of BYROW and LAMBDA. Is the word each the variable and we don't need to enclose in qoutes?

Hi Martin, I forgot to ask but how to I change this resulting range into text? The result is displayed into multiple cells and columns but I need it to display in 1 cell only. If I use TO_TEXT it only converts the 1st row TO_TEXT()

Yes, each is the name of the variable, but you can use any name you want!

I couldn't understand your second question, you need to have everything in one cell? You can try with =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,put here the formula.....)

Yes only 1 cell specifically F1. I need F1 to contain the list of all available items instead of the details occupying multiple cells.

Have you tried with what I suggested in my last comment?

Hi Martin, yes it worked! Thank you so much you are a genius!
